How to run 2 command in C++ CLI
I have a C++ application and i have two string with a command. One string is to change directory the second one is for a .exe file. I want to print the output from the command in my C++ project cli.
Code:
std::string cd = "cd " + pathToExe;
std::string cmd = "file.exe" + comport + " " + com + " turn " + angle;

I tried using:
system(cd.c_str() && cmd.c_str()); 

// here is a error --> argument of typ "bool" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"
system(cd.c_str(); cmd.c_str()); 

// here is also a error -->
expected a ')' and expected a ';'

system((cd + "; " + cmd).c_str());?

Thank you very much. Do you also know how to print the Command output in the project Command Line.

Using system from a C++ application is rare. What are you really trying to do?

system by itself is suspicious. What you should never do is call system with user input.

The user enters a angle and i call a .exe file in a other directory to change a motor in that angle. So i think i will need one "cd ...." command and one "file.exe ..." command

What if the user accidentally provides the input like "6.9 && rm -rf /", or some equivalent for windows?

Since you mentioned exe s I assume you use Windows. In that case you can use CreateProcess to run another exe (with arguments).

Re: system(cd.c_str() && cmd.c_str()); - Guessing is no way to get anywhere with C++. Read the documentation.

Instead of using cd just provide the complete path to the exceutable file thay you are trying to run. And it is better to use one of the exec variants rather than system.

A "CLI" typically refers to the interface encountered while working interactively with a shell.  If you invoke the shell via system from a C++ program, you are not using a CLI.  Are you using "CLI" to mean "shell"?

Oh, yes I mean the shell. Because the user gives me the values and I then construe a command with the values.

You need to understand what your code is attempting to do.
system(cd.c_str() && cmd.c_str()); 

This code calls cd.c_str() -- which returns a character array. Assuming it's non-null (not false), it then calls cmd.c_str(). It then does a logical AND operation on the two values, which is probably true. And that's the value it passed to system() -- which really wants a character array.
That's absolutely not what you want.
Other people have addressed using system() at all, and the dangers it can cause. But you can do a few things.
First, you can change the directory within your program using chdir():
chdir("new directory");
system(cmd.c_str());

You could chdir back if necessary when the system command completes.
Or you could make a new string:
std::string fullCommand = cd + " && " + cmd;
system(fullCommand.c_str())

The && could be ; instead. I think either would work, not that I've tested.
Or if you just want to get to the right path, but don't actually need to cd to the directory, you could specify the full path in cmd.
